# ng-repeat Not Reflecting Updates From Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem where a ng-repeat table is not reflecting updates from the server. The sequence is as follow:

Initial load of webpage invokes `$scope.$on` which calls `refreshEpisodeList()`.

`refreshEpisodeList()` gets the list of episodes from the server, and sets `$scope.episodeList` with this list. This is successfully displayed in the table on the UI using `ng-repeat="episode in episodeList"`

`updateEpisode()` is invoked via the UI to post a change to a single episode.

When the post to the server is complete, I call again
`refreshEpisodeList()`. Although the raw JSON returned by the server contains the updated information, the table on the UI is not updated

```
$scope.episodeList = [];


$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    $scope.refreshEpisodeList();
});

$scope.refreshEpisodeList= function(){

    console.log("refreshing");

    httpService.get('episode/getEpisodeList').then(function(response) { 
        $scope.episodeList = response.data;
    });     
};

//update episode and call refreshEpisodeList (to update ng-repeat table)
$scope.updateEpisode = function() {        

    httpService.post('episode/updateEpisode', $scope.episode).then(function(response) {
        $scope.refreshEpisodeList();                        
    });
  };
```

The `httpService` is:

```
app.service('httpService', function($http) {

this.get = function(url) {

    return $http.get(url)
    .success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    }).error(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });

};  

this.post = function(url, data) {

    return $http.post(url, data)
    .success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    }).error(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });

};
```

I have tried to debug this for the last few hours by looking at previous stackover questions. I realize this is a common problem but I can't get it to work. I have tried `$scope.$apply` but that returns a inprog digest error. I have tried `$scope.$applyAsync` which doesn't return an error but also doesn't update the ng-repeat. I don't believe I am preforming any tasks external to angularjs to I don't know why `$scope.$apply` would be relevant here.

I can't think what else to do to accomplish this seemingly simple task. Any advise is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I have performed some tests. If I call `refreshEpisodeList` via a button's ng-click, the table correctly updates, but it still doesn't work when `refreshEpisodeList` is called dynamically via code. I noticed a "no element found" JS error in firebug at location 1:1 of the updateEpisode function.

Comment: return to `success` does nothing...use `then()`

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the reply. Sorry I don't understand your comment. The return is working because the table is populated with data on initial page load.

Comment: right but the `success` is doing nothing

Comment: @charlietfl The `success` returns the response to `refreshEpisodeList()` which then sets `$scope.episodeList`. If I am misunderstanding something, I'd really appreciate if you could provide an answer with a correct alternative. Thanks

Comment: no it does not....there is nothing to return to in `success`, it is also deprecated in favor of using the promise callback `then()`

Comment: @charlietfl OK, I am clearly misunderstanding this then. Can you please explain how the data from the server is being displayed in the ng-repeat upon initial page load if the `success` is doing nothing?

Comment: because the `then()` in controller is providing access to the response object...completely separate from  success